# VSTO plugin not loading when installed via .MSI

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I've created a VSTO outlook plugin and it works fine when using ClickOnce deployment and installing via Setup.exe generated by ClickOnce. Now, i've used Wix to create an MSI for the same. I'm adding vsto in registry using batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
%SystemRoot%\system32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyPlugin" /v "FriendlyName" /t REG_SZ /d "MyPlugin"
%SystemRoot%\system32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyPlugin" /v "Manifest" /t REG_SZ /d "file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/MyPlugin/MyPlugin.vsto"
%SystemRoot%\system32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyPlugin" /v "Description" /t REG_SZ /d "MyPlugin"
%SystemRoot%\system32\reg.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyPlugin" /v "LoadBehavior" /t REG_DWORD /d 3
endlocal
```

This registry Key is added as expected when I run the msi.
But when i load the Outlook plugin, it's in Inactive state. The `LoadBehavior` value turns from `3` to `2`. In outlook application, LoadBehavior is `Not Loaded. A runtime error ocurred during the loading of the COM Add-in`.

The text/issue that is logged in VSTO Log:

```
Log entry added at 10:20:28 AM:
-----------Caption----------------
Microsoft Office Application Add-In
-----------Message----------------
An add-in could not be found or could not be loaded.
-----------Details----------------
Could not load file or assembly 'MyPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=73e9e1c2746dd019' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)


************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=73e9e1c2746dd019' or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
File name: 'MyPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=73e9e1c2746dd019'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.CreateEntryPoint(String entryPointTypeName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.LoadEntryPoints(IntPtr serviceProvider)
```

When I view the EventViewer, there's a VSTO4.0 error

```
This event is not displayed correctly because the underlying XML is not well formed. Below is the raw text of the event.

4096200x80000000000000265553<User machine name>Customization URI: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Microsoft Shared/VSTA/Pipeline.v10.0/PipelineSegments.store Exception: Exception reading manifest from
file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Common%20Files/Microsoft%20Shared/VSTA/Pipeline.v10.0/PipelineSegments.store: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. 
************** Exception Text ************** System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from
file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Common%20Files/Microsoft%20Shared/VSTA/Pipeline.v10.0/PipelineSegments.store: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> 
System.Xml.XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x01, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) at 
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Int32 pos, Char invChar) at
 System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace() at 
System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() at 
System.Deployment.Application.ManifestValidatingReader.XmlFilteredReader.Read() at 
System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read() at 
System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType
 manifestType, Uri sourceUri) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(
TimeSpan timeout) at 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn() ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.9151 (WinRelRS6.050727-9100) CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0 Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0 Win32 
Version: 10.0.60828.0 CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0/10.0.0.0__b
03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.v10.0.dll ----------------------------
------------ System Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.9147 (WinRelRS6.050727-
9100) CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll -
--------------------------------------- System.Core Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0 Win32 Version: 
3.5.30729.9135 built by: WinRelRS6 CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll -------
--------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0 Assembly
 Version: 10.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 10.0.60828.0 CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0/10.0.
0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.v10.0.dll ----------------
------------------------ System.AddIn Assembly Version: 3.5.0.0 Win32 Version: 3.5.30729.9135 
built by: WinRelRS6 CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.AddIn/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.AddIn.dll -----
----------------------------------- Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v9.0 Assembly Version: 9.0.0.0
 Win32 Version: 9.0.30729.7079 CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v9.0/9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v9.0.dll ---------------------------------------- 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0 Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 
10.0.60828.0 CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0/10.0.
0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.v10.0.dll ----------------
------------------------ System.Windows.Forms Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 
2.0.50727.9136 (WinRelRS6.050727-9100) CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows
.Forms.dll ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0 Win32
 Version: 2.0.50727.9136 (WinRelRS6.050727-9100) CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll -
--------------------------------------- System.Deployment Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0 Win32 Version:
 2.0.50727.9136 (WinRelRS6.050727-9100) CodeBase: 
file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Deployment/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Deployment
```

I tried to remove to all items from `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Resiliency\DisabledItems`, but still my outlook plugin is not loading.
I spent a lot of time in try different workarounds but none worked. Please help me how to resolve  this problem and load the vsto plugin successfully?

Comment: Can you open your VSTO file in Notepad to verify it is not corrupted?

Comment: Yes, i can open the vsto in Notepad

Comment: Does it looks OK?

Comment: It's an XML file, looks fine with values assigned in each tag.

Comment: The file is looking as expected. If you could tell which tag i should look for, i can share it here. I'm quiet not good with understanding of vsto and manifest file

Comment: Did you deploy the *.manifest file alongside your addin dll?

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded .NET Framework version from 4.7.2 to 4.6.1 and updated `Target Platform` & `Build Platform` from `Any CPU` to ```x86`` in VS2019. Upon doing this change, I was able to load the Add-in in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old but here is another solution in case this problem keeps happening.
If you create form regions in your Outlook vsto, you need to declare them in the registry here :

> Ordinateur\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\FormRegions\IPM.Note

My addin is called "AddinK" so I need to create the regedit key

> Ordinateur\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\FormRegions\IPM.Note

in which I add my two form regions called "myname" and "itsname" by creating 2 REG_SZ values called

> AddinK.myname

and

> AddinK.itsname

with the value

> =AddinK

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added all dll files into setup MSI.
If any important dll will be missing VSTO will not give any error exception and only removes the click event.